# localtime c++ not working as I would like to

Tags: c++, localtime

I have a problem with localtime in c++. Im using vs code and localtime_s is not working. When I use localtime it gives very large numbers for todays hour, minute and second (like "6417576:16480216:6422248"). How do I change that to something like "16:30:30" for example? I cant find any kind of information that help me, so maybe you guys will. 
Here's my code:

```
void write(string team_name)
    {
        //current time
        time_t current;
        current=time(0);
        struct tm now;
        localtime(&current);
        stringstream time;
        time<<now.tm_hour<<":"<<now.tm_min<<":"<<now.tm_sec;
        //writing filenames and times
        stringstream filename;
        filename<<"Filename"<<"_"<<team_name<<time.str()<<".txt";
        ofstream file;
        file.open(filename.str());
        file<<show();
        void print_time();
        file.close();
    }
};
```

Comment: Perhaps because you output the *uninitialized* data from the `now` structure? Think about  how to get the result that  `localtime` *returns*.

Comment: Maybe a little hint?

Comment: How do you think the result of the `localtime` call would get into the `now` structure?

Comment: You need to improve on your search skills: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+localtime, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+tm+struct.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing connecting these two statements in any way:

```
struct tm now;
localtime(&current);
```

The second statement works out everything but then *discards* the result, so all those fields in `now` are still set to whatever arbitrary value they had when the variable was created.

The `localtime` function *returns* a pointer to the structure, so you should use that:

```
struct tm *now = localtime(&current);
// use now->something
```